# css текст внизу блока - задачка

Tags: css, вёрстка

Можно ли решить данную задачу?

```css
.element1 {
  float:left;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
}

.element2 {}
```

```html
<span class="element1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="">
    <h2>Заголовок </h2>
    <span class="element2">1 000&nbsp;</span> 
    &ndash;
    <span class="element2">1 200&nbsp;</span>
</span>
```

Нужно опустить только `1 000  – 1 200` в самый низ блока `element1`Должно получиться вот так https://prnt.sc/l8k6p2

Можно редактировать только `css`

Comment: Уточните, что значит, в низ блока? Внутрь?

Comment: Чтобы `element2` был внизу блока `element1` что то типа `.element2{position:absolute;
bottom: 0;}` только внутри блока

Comment: @НикитаФаст к сожалению можно редактировать только `.element2` к `.element1` привязано много кодов и стилей которые слетают :( `.element1` тащит за собой весь контент.

Comment: @НикитаФаст в `element1` входят: картинка, название и диапазон цен под названием `element2` Если редактировать `element1` то он автоматом тащит все за собой: картинку, название и т.д. Можно редактировать только `.element2` Извиняюсь за не правильную информацию.

Comment: ПУБЛИКА ХОРОШ МИНУСОВАТЬ

Comment: Полный код это плагин `woocommerce` здесь не реально его публиковать да и смысл не в этом. Реально опустить `.element2` редактированием только css `.element2` ?? Или все таки в php нужно лезть :/

Comment: @НикитаФаст, у каждого есть своё право на выбор=) (+ или -)

Comment: десять раз перечитал, так и не понял в чем суть проблемы, о чем вопрос...

Comment: @Air у неё не та проблема что описана в вопросе , у неё woocommerce и у ней в родительской обёртке есть : img и что то ещё и вот это что то ещё это : span.element2 + тире + span.element2 и дело в том что она не умеет или не может обернуть это в php и потому спрашивает как опустить все три элемента в самый низ ....понятно что к span мы можем обратится по nth-of-type но вот как обратиться к ndash ? флексбокс не подходит так как есть изображение и все элементы встанут в линию или в столбик если это column ... надеюсь поняли и потому в чате я опросил её и самое лучшее это обернуть всё что не img

Comment: Я не понимаю, Кто вообще дает одинаковые наименования классам, при том что они должны выполнять разные задачи, размещаться в разных местах (относительно точки) и нести в себе разные данные (отличные друг от друга)

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич это разметка woocommerce

Answer (score 1):

Надо обернуть ваши эти `element2 + тире + element2` в какую то обёртку...

Я долго искал решение и обратился [сюда](https://toster.ru/q/572668)

в общем в woocommerce уже подключен jQuery и именно на нём мы и обернём эти три элемента.

Нужен нам css файл вашей темы и jquery файл но общий не от вашей темы 
где мы напишем следующее при такой вёрстке:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".element1:not({img})").wrapInner("<span class='item'></span>");
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element1 {
  display: block;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.span.item img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

span.item {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="element1">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x300" alt="">
<span class="element2">
1 000&nbsp;
</span> &ndash;
<span class="element2">
1 200&nbsp;
</span>
</span>

<span class="element1">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x300" alt="">
<span class="element2">
1 000&nbsp;
</span> &ndash;
<span class="element2">
1 200&nbsp;
</span>
</span>

<span class="element1">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x300" alt="">
<span class="element2">
1 000&nbsp;
</span> &ndash;
<span class="element2">
1 200&nbsp;
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Так `1 000  – 1 200` в итоге не передвинулись вниз. Должно получится вот так https://prnt.sc/l8k6p2

Comment: @ЮляФролова  вы нашли jquery и css файлы вашей темы ?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант в разметку можно внести коррективу, т.е. добавить к элементу родителю еще 1 класс и тогда не придется менять верстку для всех элементов, связанных с классом element1. И после этого, используя flexbox'ы можно легко добиться нужного результата:

```css
.element1 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 350px;
}
.custom{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.element2 {
  
}
```

```html
<span class="custom element1">
    <span class="element2">1 000&nbsp;</span> 
    &ndash;
    <span class="element2">1 200&nbsp;</span>
</span>
```

Если нет возможности менять разметку, то можно обратиться к нужному элементу с классом element1 через псевдоселекторы, родителя, сестринские элементы и т.д.

Comment: я ей делал - так но это не подходит

Comment: @НикитаФаст любой плагин можно подогнать под себя, так что не вижу проблемы

Comment: вы не поняли меня ....

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое всем кто принимал участие в дискуссии. Отдельную благодарность хочу выразить за активное участие @НикитаФаст Вопрос решен следующим образом:

Пришлось все таки писать свой плагин и обернуть `element2`в дополнительный класс. Решение через jquery скорее всего правильное, но если и лезть в код то лучше переписать плагин полностью под себя.

```
<span class="element1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200" alt="">
    <h2>Заголовок </h2>
    <span class="el-3">
    <span class="element2">1 000&nbsp;</span> 
    &ndash;
    <span class="element2">1 200&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
</span>
```